# What argtype when input parameter is: numpy.ndarray.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte))?

Tags: c++, wrapper, ctypes

I've wrapped a C++-file for python (C++, C-api, Ctypes). This C++ file returns images (video from webcam or IP-cam). 
In the python file I create an numpy.ndarray with zeros that I send as an pointer to the C++ object which fills that memory space with a new cam frame.

The C-api:

```
extern "C" void getFrame(cam* camera, int rows, int cols, int channels, unsigned char *indata) {...}
```

(I use the "indata" to create an cv::Mat that I can copy a cam frame to)

Which I have wrapped with a python file that has the following call:
(import ctypes as C)

```
camLib = C.cdll.LoadLibrary('./camCon.so')
...
camLib.getFrame.argtypes = (C.c_void_p, C.c_int,C.c_int,C.c_int,C.c_ubyte)
camLib.getFrame(self.obj, self.frame_height, self.frame_width, channels, self.newCamFrame.ctypes.data_as(C.POINTER(C.c_ubyte)))
```

But I get an error:

```
videoConLib.getFrame(self.obj, self.frame_height, self.frame_width, channels, self.newCamFrame.ctypes.data_as(C.POINTER(C.c_ubyte)))
ArgumentError: argument 5: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: wrong type
```

So my question is. What type should I use for the last parameter (self.newCamFrame.ctypes.data_as(C.POINTER(C.c_ubyte))

I Tried the following:

```
print "TYPE: ", self.newCamFrame.ctypes.data_as(C.POINTER(C.c_ubyte))._type_
```

Which gave me the following output:

```
TYPE:  <class 'ctypes.c_ubyte'>
```

I also wonder, is it correct to use "ctypes.c_void_p" as argtype for the pointer to the object created by the class in C++/C file?

I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Thanks!

Comment: Minimally, you can use `c_void_p` in `argtypes` and pass `self.newCamFrame.ctypes` because `newCamFrame.ctypes._as_parameter_` is an instance of `c_void_p`.

Comment: If you want to limit the parameter for better type safety, as well as make it simpler to pass the array, you can use a special subclass of `c_void_p` that handles checking the type of a NumPy array, e.g. `frame_t = numpy.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype='uint8', ndim=3, flags='C')`. Set that in `argtypes`, and you can pass `self.newCamFrame` directly, given it has the specified data type, dimensions, and is C contiguous.

Comment: The base class of a non-simple pointer type (i.e. *not* `c_void_p` or `c_char_p`) is `ctypes._Pointer`. The call `POINTER(c_ubyte)` translates to `type(_Pointer)('LP_%s' % c_ubyte.__name__, (_Pointer,), {'_type_': c_ubyte})`, where `_type_` is the type that the pointer type references. The `POINTER` function caches the resulting pointer type in `ctypes._pointer_type_cache` for future use, with the referenced type as the key.

Comment: Thanks! You solved it for me. Please reply with an answer so that I can mark it as the correct answer.